# How to use pathlib.Path in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm using pathlib.Path as an alternative to os.path, and I'm trying to use it for the directory paths in the django project, but how much do I try to create migrations, the error occurs:

```
"return database_name == ': memory:' or 'mode = memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable "
```

And my base dir:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent
```

Database join:

```
BASE_DIR.joinpath('db.sqlite3')
```

Answer (score 3):

`pathlib.Path`s are not strings (or bytes). Most internal Django code uses the `os.path` functions, and those require strings/bytes, and code that expects a string (like it looks like `database_name` is expecting) cannot work with `pathlib.Path` objects -- you'll need to convert it to string (ie. `str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('db.sqlite3')`

It's possible to write a Path class that is a subclass of `str`, which makes interaction with code that expects string much more transparent (many have created such classes, including me: https://github.com/datakortet/dkfileutils/blob/master/dkfileutils/path.py).

Comment: is there any tutorial on Path and OS? Documentation is not task-oriented, and since I'm a beginner, I get a little lost.

Comment: Don't know of any of the top of my head (I tend to snuggle up with a library reference on lonely nights, so I might not be the best person to ask... ;-)

Comment: Converting to string is the idea for `pathlib` to work with `django`

Answer (score 1):

Your use case can even be a little simpler:

```
BASE_DIR = Path.cwd()
DATABASE.NAME = str(BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3")
```

Note: The conversion to a string, because Django can't yet handle Pathlib instances.